# Print a Perl hash of hashes

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, dbi

I am building a hash of hashes. How can I use `while` to get each value?

```
my %users = ();

while ( my $row_ref = $select_sth->fetchrow_hashref() ) {

    $id     = $row_ref->{uid};
    $name   = $row_ref->{name};
    my $loc = $row_ref->{loc };

    $users{$loc}{$name} = $id;
}

while ( my ($user, $val) = each(%users) ) {

    # how to get name, loc, id?

    my $uname = ??
    my $uloc  = ??
    my $uid   = ??
}
```

Comment: Why have you declared `my $loc` but not `$id` or `$name`?

Answer (score 7):

Iterate over the two levels of the hash in nested loops.

```
for my $loc (keys %users) {
    for my $name (keys $users{$loc}->%*) {
        say "loc: $loc -- name: $name -- id: $users{$loc}{$name}";
    }
}
```

Hint: use [Data::Dumper](http://p3rl.org/Data::Dumper) or similar to visualise a nested data structure.